# Unit of Work with Enterprise library

Tags: .net, design-patterns, enterprise-library

how could I apply the unit of work pattern using only enterprise library data access?
I'm using a interface (IRepository) with all default methods that repositories must implements. But how could I achive UoW with enterprise library? A lot of examples are using EntityFramework and NHibernate.

Thanks.